# How to set a drawText in a SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, drawtext

Well I've createad a SurfaceView that displays a bitmap, without problems. But I want to display a Text in the bottom of the screen, I think it can be called the canvas.

I tried to draw the text the same way than i did with the bitmap, but without success. I get de force close error.

I've got something like this:

```
        public void run() {

        while (isRunning) {
            if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            canvas.drawText(score, 200, 100, null);

            canvas.drawBitmap(enemy1, enemy1X, enemy1Y, null); // DRAW FIRST
                                                                // ENEMY

            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

I already tried to set up a new Paint too, instead of using the "null", but it didn't worked as well :/

Can you please tell how it must be done, or why it isn't working. Im new to Android Programming...

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange. Сode looks clear. 
The picture does not cover the text?

Yet assign a text paint and set the color. Try this for tests:

```
Canvas canvas = null;
try {
    canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
    synchronized (ourHolder) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(enemy1, enemy1X, enemy1Y, null);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawText("XXXX", 200, 100, paint);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "run() lockCanvas()", e);
} finally {
    if (canvas != null) {
        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

**ADD**

The SurfaceView dimension is greater than 200х100? Try `canvas.drawText("XXXX", 20, 20, paint);`

Comment: I will try that when I get home. I dont know if the background is covering the text because i cant even run the app.  Why the "synchronized" ?

Comment: Good question... I searched a bit but could not find an answer. I am also a beginner. Who knows the answer?

Comment: hum, i don't know about the SurfaceView dimensions... Im kinda lost with the dimensions, because something can look great on my phone, but not in another, with a bigger screen, per example. How can i work with that?

Comment: Ok, now Im completely lost haha. I tested your sugestion with the synchronized thing and everything and it worked just fine... The text appears, with the correct color and etc. But, I just don't completely understand the code... :/

Comment: Transform code, step by step from your initial code to my suggested, and you will find problem. Pay attention to Logcat, add some own messages for debugging. Try, modify, debug.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try it, and if i have any doubt i post here. ;)